# Text overflow in Flutter App in InputDecoration

Tags: flutter

I am using InputDecoration to put a hint text in Flutter App. But when I run the app, the text overflown which is not I want as it does not help the user to do it.

```html
decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
    hintText: 'Enter in numbers (gram)',
    helperText: 'Select teaspoon or tablespoon and click "Calculate" button for Water',
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
),
```

I have tried to use Text function at helperText but it has error where Text argument cannot be converted into String. I would prefer to do in InputDecoration rather than using Text function separately. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not add some small helper Text, Its too long

Comment: how do you want it to be exactly? show text in 2 lines?

Comment: @s_erfani - Yes, I want the text to appear in 2 lines so that it does not overflown.                        Bensal - I will consider it because I want to put instruction to user when they first using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `helperMaxLine`:

```
InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
            hintText: 'Enter in numbers (gram)',
            helperText: 'Select teaspoon or tablespoon and click "Calculate" button for Water',
            helperMaxLines: 2,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            icon: Icon(Icons.send),
          ),
```